# Query on the method to prove that $f(x)=x^4-2x^2+8x+1\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

We wish to show that $f(x)=x^4-2x^2+8x+1\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Do I need to consider two cases 1. If $f(x)$ contains a linear factor and 2. If $f(x)$ factors into two quadratic factors, to answer this problem?

Or it is enough to use the contrapositive of the theorem stating that:

If $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $a_0\neq 0$ and if $f(x)$ has a zero in $\mathbb{Q}$, then it has a zero $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $m$ must divide $a_0$.

Here is my attempt to answer the problem.

Consider $f(x)=x^4-2x^2+8x+1$ viewed in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Since $a_0=1\neq 0$ the possible zeroes of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ are those integers that divide $1$, which are exactly $\pm 1$. But $\pm 1$ are not both zeroes of $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Thus by the contrapositive of the theorem, $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: **Hint** $\ (x^2+1)^2\,$ has no rational roots but *is* reducible.

Comment: What you prove is that $f(x)$ doesn't have a linear factor; you still need to prove that it doesn't factor as two quadratic polynomials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having no roots doesn't mean the polynomial is irreducible.

It is however true that, since the polynomial is monic, irreducibility in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is equivalent to irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. It has no linear factor, so it is irreducible if and only if it cannot be split into the product of two (monic) quadratic factors.

Say $x^4-2x^2+8x+1=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$. Then $bd=1$, so we can restrict to the cases $b=d=1$ or $b=d=-1$.

Try both cases and you're done.

Comment: I understand now. Expanding the right hand side of the equation and using the fact that it is equal to the left hand side gives $bd=1$, $ad+bc=8$,  $ac+b+d=-2$ and $a+c=0$.

Comment: Then $bd=1$ means b and d are equal. If this is the case $ad+bc=ad+dc=d(a+c)=8$. A contradiction arise since $a+c=0$.

Comment: @JrAntalan Yes; in case $b=d=1$, you get $a+c$ both as the coefficient of $x^3$ and $x$; in case $b=d=-1$, you get $a+c$ as the coefficient of $x^3$ and $-(a+c)$ as the coefficient for $x$.